# How do I compare two columns for repeated values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the id of several users and their respective friends ID, I want to see who has a mutual friend.

Example, 1 is the ID of Roger and 2 is the id of Matt.

TABLE FRIENDS
FIELDS/VALUES:

```
ID, FRIEND_ID, FRIEND_NAME

1, 34, DAMON

1, 17, RICHARD

1, 56, DANIEL

1, 65, CHARLIE

2, 15, PRISCILA

2, 17, RICHARD

2, 45, JOHN

2, 56, DANIEL
```

I want to create a select with ID 1 and 2, that will return the rows that have the FRIEND_ID in common(meaning which friend Roger and Matt have in common), in this case, it would return the cols with the friend_id RICHARD and DANIEL, preferably, not duplicated.

Comment: why is friends_name in this table? Friend has already an id, so I assume friend is stored in another table, with it's name etc...

Comment: @DirkMcQuickly: It is reasonable and commonplace to denormalize the tables slightly for the sake of performance. If a friend's name is often accessed, it is faster to pick it up from here than do a Join every time.

Comment: OK. I did not know this. But how do you guarantee the integrity of you data? Can you point me to a good tutorial about this? My solution would be to create a VIEW with the id and name therein and query this

Comment: Dirk, the names are in another table, I put that there only to explain better, also, the real table is a little bit bigger than that, but it was unnecessary to put it all.

Comment: So why didn't you say so in your first reply? Or is it really commonplace to denormalize your tables?

Comment: @DirkMcQuickly: It is commonplace to denormalize tables in extremely high volume situations. In this case, data integrity is no longer ensured and you need to be careful when you make changes. Here's a good article on how FB denormalized tables to support the timeline feature. https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/building-timeline-scaling-up-to-hold-your-life-story/10150468255628920

Comment: @xbonez thanks for that. I thought I smelled a bit of bs, especially since TP states that he is a noob concerning db. So I apologize to von Goethe if my tone was too harsh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work,

```
Select f1.FRIEND_ID,f1.FRIEND_NAME from 
FRIENDS f1,FRIENDS f2 where f1.FRIEND_ID =f2.FRIEND_ID and 
f1.id=1 and f2.id=2
```

here is the sample:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9f36/1/0

also if you want to get all people having common friends try this

```
Select f1.FRIEND_ID,f1.FRIEND_NAME,f1.id 'first person',f2.id as 'second person' from 
FRIENDS f1,FRIENDS f2 where f1.FRIEND_ID =f2.FRIEND_ID and 
f1.id<>f2.id and f1.id<f2.id
```

this will return two people having same friends per row: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9f36/2/0

Comment: It worked flawlessly! Thank you Ankur, I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to db.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT friend_id, friend_name
FROM friends
WHERE id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY friend_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cd2e/3)**.